# Data classification from list of data in Ms. Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

This is my first question in StackOverflow. I hope my question is clear for you.

I have problem about data classification problem in Ms. Excel. Here is the problem. Let say I have a rows of data in this format: id, position, and item.
I want to make classification/grouping on the data which shares the same item on each position.

In order to make this easier to understand, I will give some examples.

Source Data:

| ID | Position | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | layer-0 | ProductA |
| X2 | layer-0 | ProductA |
| X3 | layer-0 | ProductB |
| X4 | layer-0 | ProductB |
| X5 | layer-0 | ProductC |
| X6 | layer-0 | ProductD |
| X1 | layer-1 | ProductA |
| X2 | layer-1 | ProductA |
| X3 | layer-1 | ProductA |
| X4 | layer-1 | ProductB |
| X5 | layer-1 | ProductC |
| X6 | layer-1 | ProductD |
| X1 | layer-2 | ProductB |
| X2 | layer-2 | ProductB |
| X3 | layer-2 | ProductC |
| X4 | layer-2 | ProductC |
| X5 | layer-2 | ProductC |
| X6 | layer-2 | ProductD |
| X1 | layer-3 | ProductC |
| X4 | layer-3 | ProductC |

Expected Output

- Group 1: X1, X2
- Group 2: X3
- Group 3: X4
- Group 4: X5
- Group 5: X6

Note that the ID "X1" and "X2" are grouped together because

- on "layer-0", both X1 and X2 has product value of "ProductA".
- on "layer-1", both X1 and X2 has product value of "ProductA",
- on "layer-2", both X1 and X2 has product value of "ProductB",
- on "layer-3", X1 has product value of "ProductC". But no data is available on X2. Hence it is assumed that X2 has the same value with X1. Hence, X1 and X2 is classified on the same group. {it uses the same item for every position]

For X3, X4, X5, X6 are grouped separately, because they do not shares the same item value on every layer.

- X3 --> Layer-0: ProductB, Layer-1: ProductA, Layer-2: ProductC
- X4 --> Layer-0: ProductB, Layer-1: ProductB, Layer-2: ProductC, Layer-3: ProductC
- X5 --> Layer-0: ProductC, Layer-1: ProductC, Layer-2: ProductC
- X6 --> Layer-0: ProductD, Layer-1: ProductD, Layer-2: ProductD

How can I do this type of data classification using Ms. Excel Visual Basic?

Comment: You tagged Excel 2010, please confirm that's really your version, this seems better achievable in Office 365.

Comment: Hello, Yes this problem is for Excel 2010. Since the company I worked on still uses Excel 2010 version.

Comment: Will your company allow you to download and install Microsoft's free Power Query add-in for Excel 2010?

Comment: I lose the logic at: *on "layer-3", X1 has product value of "ProductC". But no data is available on X2. Hence it is assumed that X2 has the same value with X1. Hence, X1 and X2 is classified on the same group. {it uses the same item for every position]*
Why is it assumed to be the same?